# Trouble sending Push notifications from user to user using Parse and Swift

Tags: swift, push-notification, parse-platform, ios8

I'm having trouble sending push notifications from user to user. I'm using a Parse backend, and all of my code is in Swift. I can add a push notification to the server without issue, but I can't seem to add a push notification receiver without getting an error that highlights [PFInternalUtils assertValidClassForQuery:]. I know it has something to do with how I'm querying for the recipient, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Here is my complete code:

```
    let message: NSString = responseMessage.text as NSString

    var data = [ "title": "Some Title",
                 "alert": message]

    var userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    userQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: recipientObjectId)
    var query: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()
    query.whereKey("currentUser", equalTo: userQuery)

    var push: PFPush = PFPush()
    push.setQuery(query)
    push.setData(data)
    push.sendPushInBackground()
```

**This Works**
If I take out the query, the code works with just sending a push notification to Parse:

```
    let message: NSString = responseMessage.text as NSString

    var data = [ "title": "Some Title",
                 "alert": message]

    var push: PFPush = PFPush()
    push.setData(data)
    push.sendPushInBackground()
```

**This is the suspect code**

```
    var userQuery: PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    userQuery.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: recipientObjectId)
    var query: PFQuery = PFInstallation.query()
    query.whereKey("currentUser", equalTo: userQuery)

    push.setQuery(query)
```

**Also For Reference**

recipientObjectId is the objectId of the user that is supposed to receive the push notification. It is saved as an NSString.

The "currentUser" key in my installation class is a pointer to the user that owns the installation.

**EDIT**

Forgot to give the console output. The console output reads: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: PFQuery'

Comment: Dear user3353890; Can you provide the console output where you get the error [PFInternalUtils assertValidClassForQuery:]? Regards.

Comment: Of course! My mistake. I had an exception breakpoint on and forget to turn it off to get the console output...the output error states: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: PFQuery' ...I will also amend my question with that.

Comment: Dear user3353890; can you check the your user query if it return result? I think there is a problem related with return User object(relation).

Comment: Yes, the userQuery returns an object of the User class. It returns the entire dictionary for the user that I'm searching for. objectId, username, email, etc....

Comment: Dear user3353890,

As far as I know, if  you have a column which is type of Pointer<_User> on Installation table  your Push query have to work. Please check again the Push Notification document of Parse which is below link;

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-queries/iOS

Hope this helps,
Regards.if you

Comment: figured it out! Thanks for your help. I feel dumb now....instead of using (whereKey, equalTo) the correct method is (whereKey, matchesQuery). Thanks again! I post the correct code below as well.

Comment: I'm trying to learn from this code to send push notifications between devices (see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32348743/sending-push-notifications-between-devices-using-parse-and-swift)), but I'm not sure what "responseText" is referring to. Could you provide some guidance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the Answer!

Instead of using

```
query.whereKey("currentUser", equalTo: userQuery)
```

**The Correct Code Is**

```
query.whereKey("currentUser", matchesQuery: userQuery)
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the complete code? Bit confused from all the different ways you tried in your question and then which code you ended up using in its entirety. @user3353890