# Sending push notifications between devices using Parse and Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification

I have configured my app to receive push notifications through Parse, which I can send from the Parse dashboard, but I would like to send notifications between devices, specifically when a button is clicked from either device. I cannot find documentation about this...wondering if anyone has experience doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the current user into Installation class then send push notification using PFInstallation Query and PFPush.

Please refer this parse documentation for more details to send notification.
https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications
or refer this site [Swift Parse : How to Push Notification To a Specific Device/objectId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30088077/swift-parse-how-to-push-notification-to-a-specific-device-objectid)

Comment: I'm new to Parse, how would I access the user's name on the parse dashboard? Would they have to sign up for my app? I'm just doing this between two phones, but I dont see a list of users on the dashboard...

Comment: you have to signup the user from your app and then you will select user and send push notification from parse dashboard.

Comment: So I have to include signup code even if it's just for 2 users total? Is that code in the docs?